# Insufficient privileges Sonarqube WebService API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I try using the sonarqube web API to find duplicated source code, but I get the error message.

```
{"errors":[{"msg":"Insufficient privileges"}]}
```

I have tried it on version 5.1 and 4.5 LTS.

I set all permissions to "anyone".

Also I've tried to send a Base64 authentication in java, but it always returns "403".

```
    URL url = new URL("");

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    String password = "admin:admin";

    String base = "Base " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(password.getBytes());        

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", base);


    connection.connect();


    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    String line;

    while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

I have found nothing, that works for me in the documentation.

I can't understand, why it doesn't work for me.

Actually I'm on version 5.1

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

`String base = "Base " +` shouldn't this be `String base = "Basic " +`

Comment: Hmm, what url are you trying to access?

Comment: This is my URL `http://localhost:9000/api/sources/scm?key=myProject:src/de/myCompany/utils/MyClass.java`

Comment: Ok, it seems weird why it won't work. Just to eliminate anything wrong with the code, can you try calling the API using a REST client like Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)  Specify the auth header and try making the same call

Comment: I fixed everythind in the Code and I have called it using RestClient Addon in Firefox with Authorization admin:admin, which is my Admin-Login in SonarQube, but i still get the same error.